# Adding one matrix with another matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to add a matrix with another matrix in MATLAB.

The first matrix looks like this:

```
0.0963928845397177  1.30250820960714
-0.830468497619261  1.40991150001902
-0.352252185662263  -1.66254297035808
-0.174775039544099  1.94368447839214
-0.480653419481013  -1.08469845223762
0.836836711417678   0.226818975021420
2.53834934138902    1.09892920248474
-1.32333425148040   0.147188752472257
0.128340263343307   2.29566581301284
-1.44237915336114   2.75255787759549
```

Second matrix looks like this:

```
[1 2]
```

I want to add the second matrix with the first matrix => meaning 0.0963928845397177+1 and 1.30250820960714+2. I want to add 1 to first column and 2 to second column.

What i have tried:

```
secondmatrix .+ firstmatrix
```

But it is not working..

Need some guidance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either;

```
A = ones(5,2)
B=[1,2]
C = A+repmat(B,size(A,1),1)
```

or

```
C = [A(:,1)+B(1,1) A(:,2)+B(1,2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably best to avoid `repmat` if you can for efficiency purposes if you're going to use this with large matrices. Similarly with the `[A(:,1)+b(1) A(:,2)+b(2)]` approach. I'm a fan of `bsxfun`:

```
bsxfun(@plus, A, b)
```

Comment: Might be an overkill with just two elements in `Second matrix`. Good to see a `bsxfun` fan nevertheless! :)

Comment: Yeah that's true. My instinct though is to throw `bsxfun` and similar methods in wherever they're applicable :). A quick test shows that `bsxfun` does about as well as `repmat` for small `A`; as `size(A,1) > 1000` or so `bsxfun` inches ahead

Comment: Well of course `bsxfun` would win against `repmat` for decent sized inputs, but I meant it would probably be still slower than `C = [A(:,1)+B(1,1) A(:,2)+B(1,2)]` solution.

Comment: +1 for me too.  I'm a `bsxfun` fan myself

Comment: Who could _not_ be a fan of `bsxfun`? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Either what [Jommy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247647/3372061) suggested, or you can replicate the smaller matrix to make it the same size, and then add like so:

```
C = A + repmat(B,[size(A,1),1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 sum_ = first_matrix + repmat(second_matrix,size(first_matrix,1),1);
```

Comment: It's bad practice to name your variable `sum` because this is a function name in MATLAB....

Answer (score 2):

Matlab provides a function for what you want to do, [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which "Apply element-by-element binary operation to two arrays with singleton expansion enabled"

The example code:

```
result_matrix = bsxfun(@plus, firstmatrix, secondmatrix);
```

Comment: Might be an overkill with just two elements in `Second matrix`.

Comment: It takes the same time than repmat or similar for small matrixes. And IMHO it's a cleaner code, no matter the matrix size.

Comment: Agreed on the cleaner code idea!

Comment: +1 for me too.  I agree this is cleaner code, and I'm a `bsxfun` fan myself.  I have @Divakar to thank for that!

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is the large matrix and `B` is the small one you can write

```
C = [A(:,1)+B(1) A(:,2)+B(2)];
```

Another possibility is

```
C = A + repmat(B, [length(A) 1]);
```

Comment: Watch out when using `length()` because it will not work in a similar scenario where there are more columns than rows in `A`.

Comment: I haven't ever noticed this behavior. Thank you!